# php class only returns 1st line of results

Tags: php, mysql

so basically i have a DB table with:

id, user_id, occupation, years, highest_position

i've created a class:

```
class WorkHistory {
    public $id;
    public $user_id;
    public $ocupation;
    public $years;
    public $highest_position;

    //construct work history based on user id
    public function __construct($id=null){
        $this->id = $id;
        WorkHistoryWrapper::getHistory($this);
    }

    //update user history
//    public function update(){
//        UserWrapper::updateHistory($this);
//    }
}


class WorkHistoryWrapper extends WorkHistory {
    //get user work history
    static public function getHistory($WorkHistory){
        global $mysqli;

        //get user info according to user id
        $WorkHistoryQuery = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT user_id, ocupation, years, highest_position
        FROM work_history
      WHERE user_id = ? LIMIT 200");

        $WorkHistoryQuery->bind_param('s', $WorkHistory->id);  // Bind "$id" to parameter.
        $WorkHistoryQuery->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
        $WorkHistoryQuery->store_result();

        // get variables from result.
        $WorkHistoryQuery->bind_result($WorkHistory->user_id, $WorkHistory->ocupation, $WorkHistory->years, $WorkHistory->highest_position);
        $WorkHistoryQuery->fetch();
        return $WorkHistory;
    }
}
```

Then i'm pulling the class by doing the following:

```
$wh = new WorkHistory($logged_user);
```

when i do:

```
print_r($wh);
```

it returns:

WorkHistory Object ( [id] => 3 [user_id] => 3 [ocupation] => Ninja [years] => 100 [highest_position] => Black Belt )

however this is only the first result, how do i get the other results?

cheers,
dan

Comment: Remove/Change the `WHERE` clause in your query so you can have all the results; Or make your call and use of your `id` as array.

Comment: Read your sql query again specifically focus on `WHERE` clause. What will return if you execute this query on workbench or in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

`$WorkHistoryQuery->fetch();` will only returns a single record unless you use while loop.

You need to try a [fetch_all](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) method to do this.

Also look into your where condition. If `user_id` is unique then it will returns only single record because of your `where` condition.